# Automate Outlook Emails with Attachments in Excel

Tags: email, attachment

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following 5 columns:

1. Invoice Number, 2) Company, 3) Primary Email address, 4) Secondary Email address(es), 5) Account Number

I also have a folder that contains invoices.  Each invoice has the invoice number in its file name -- i.e., Inv_123456.pdf

I want to build an excel macro that -- when I provide a list of invoice number(s) will:

1. Open an email --  To: <Primary Contact, Cc: <Secondary contacts, and Bcc: <me,
2. Put the Invoice Number in the subject, and
3. Go to the folder containing the invoices and attach the corresponding invoice named InvNo_*.pdf, i.e., InvNo_123456.pdf

This is repeated for each invoice number and the email is displayed for review.  *Initially, I want to display the email w/attachment until I am comfortable the macro works as expected.

The path to the folder containing the pre-filled invoices is --
C:\Users\christma-2\OneDrive - OurYear2Win\Documents\Clorodet\Invoice Emails\Attachments\Invoice_*.pdf

Following is the macro I've created so far.  I would like to pull the invoice with the corresponding invoice number and attach it to the email.

```vb
Sub Send_Email_to_List()

Dim OL As Object, MailSendItem As Object
Dim MsgTxt As String

Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each xCell In ActiveSheet.Range(Range("C1"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    user_email = xCell.Value
    user_subject = "Subject Line for the Email"
    user_msg = "Thank You For Submitting this email"

    Set MailSendItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With MailSendItem
        .Subject = user_subject
        .Body = user_msg
        .To = user_email
        .CC = " "
        .Bcc = "clorodet20607@aol.com"
'I need help getting the correct attachment, putting the invoice number in the subject, and cc'ing the secondary contacts
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Users\christma-2\OneDrive - OurYear2Win\Documents\Clorodet\Invoice Emails\Attachments\W1\???.pdf")
        .Display
    End With

Next xCell

Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> Find the corresponding contact's email address -- To: <Primary Contact, Cc: <Secondary contacts, and Bcc: <me,

You can use the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method creates a `Recipient` object. The name of the recipient; it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient. So, there is no need to search for the contact.

```
Sub ResolveName()  
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace  
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")  
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev")  

 myRecipient.Resolve  

 If myRecipient.Resolved Then  
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 End If 
 
End Sub  
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient)  
 Dim CalendarFolder As Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
 
End Sub
```

You can get a `Contact` instance by using the following sequence of calls:

```
recipient.AddressEntry.GetContact()
```

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I will be pulling records from a large database and sending the email to a select number of people from the list at the same time.   My understanding of the CreateRecipient method requires responding 1 at a time so I don't think the CreateRecipient method will work in my case.

Comment: To find a contact with a specified name or email address is that what you need. You can set up the `Recipients` collection in the way you need.

Comment: My vlookup works fine.  I'm need help with pulling the corresponding invoice from the folder and attaching it to the email, handling the email's subject line so it contains the invoice number, and populating the CC: part of the email.  I'm sorry I was not clear but I really appreciate any help you can provide.